# Integrate external Native apps inside React Native app

Tags: android, ios, react-native

Hope you can help me with this problem.

I have a React Native app and I need to implement a feature that uses some specific functionalities from another external native app in Android and iOS.
Here's the catch: the external app uses some client SDK that needs to be inside the app and there's no way to integrate the entire app inside the React Native app due to confidentiality issues. Is there a way to integrate APK and IPA files inside the React Native app to use them as an internal service app or to install them automatically when the main app is installed? Of course the user would be informed about the second case.

So you have 2 apps and one of them wants to use a funcionality of the other but the second app isn't yours and must not be open sourced inside your app project. This funcionality doesn't require visual implementation, only system access and logic implementation (like a internal service provider for the React Native app). The easiest solution would be to build a Native module for React Native and install it as a dependency inside the React Native app. Unfortunately, this is not possible because the app owners don't want to make their code to be accessible in any way.

I really need some help to figure this out. For me, the optimal solution is to somehow incorporate the external native app inside the React Native app and it runs like an internal service app for the main app, like if it "explodes" inside the app when it's installed and remain code secured and not accessible for anyone.

The problem is that this is very advanced and I don't know how to solve this.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you tried  deep linking - https://reactnative.dev/docs/linking

Comment: Deep linking is in fact a solution but the idea is to call a service from another app while staying in the same app. For example, you take a picture from one app and you want to process that picture in a service from another app that responds with the processed data while staying in the first app. The real question is, can I do this without forcing the user to install a second app from the store, i.e., having that second app integrated inside the bundle without having access to that specific code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.